# Hide "!DOCTYPE html" in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

We managed to embed a html-table with iframe. At the very top of the table you can read "!DOCTYTE html". What do I have to include in the iframe-command that this "!DOCTYTE html" doesn't show up anymore?

My code so far:

`<iframe src="http://test/positiveFaelle.html" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" frameBorder="0"    width="900" height="485"></iframe>`

The result:

[image]

Comment: Sounds highly unlikely unless the file contains &lt;DOCTYPE... or the server serves the file as plain text

Comment: The problem is probably in the page that delivers the contents of the iframe, not the iframe itself. Check your http://test/positiveFaelle.html file!

Comment: My positiveFaelle.html contains <p>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt
I generate this html-file automatically with R (save_kable).

Comment: Yep so there is your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with your *test/positiveFaelle.html* file.

The content should look something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If in your file you have `&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;` it wont work.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Isn't &lt; the equivalent of <? 
Any idea on how to replace that `&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;` when using save_kable in R?